# Maintain Insertion Order in a Sorted Table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table that allow me to insert a new row above or below another row. The table can be sorted by column.

The problem is that new rows with empty fields that are added into my sorted table will always appear on the top of the table.

This is the HTML:

```
<table>
    <th ng-repeat= "header in headers">
        <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='name'; reverseSort = !reverseSort"> Name </a>
    </th>
    <tr ng-repeat "result in results | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
        <td> 
          <span>{{result}}</span>
          <md-icon ng-click="addRow(result, true)"></md-icon>
          <md-icon ng-click="addRow(result, false)"></md-icon>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my controller:

```
function addRow(selectedRow, isAbove) {
  var selectedPos = $scope.results.indexOf(selectedRow);
  var newRow = "";

  if (isAbove) {
    $scope.results.splice(selectedPos, 0, newRow);
  } else {
    $scope.results.splice(selectedPos + 1, 0, newRow);
  }
}
```

So if my table looks like this, after sorting:

```
[Before sort]       [After sort]

Name                Name
----                ----
D                   A
----                ----
C                   B
----                ----
B                   C
----                ----
A                   D
----                ----
```

and I insert a new row above and below **D**, my table now looks like this:

```
Name 
-----
""
-----
""
-----
A
-----
B
-----
C
-----
D
-----
```

Expected result:

```
Name
----
A
----
B
----
C
----
""
----
D
----
""
----
```

Why is it that the new rows don't appear directly above or below the row that I've chosen to add from?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, I think you'll want to share the code used to add a row.

Comment: @brian hi, I've edited my question to include the code used to add a row.

Comment: I'm not real familiar with the stack, but if I had to take a guess I'd suspect that selectedPos is not getting the value you expect. Look into that results.indexOf() line.

Comment: Because the rows are being sorted and "" comes before the other items.

Comment: @Dan are there solutions to not sort the newly added rows

Comment: Yes, but probably much more complicated than it seems. But it's hard to imagine a scenario where that would be helpful. When would you want to insert rows but have them permanently slotted? What if the sort is reversed, should they move?

Comment: @Dan My application has to maintain the inserted order, unless the "sort" button is clicked on again.. so yes, if the sort is reversed, they should move, else they shouldn't.

Comment: If it's ordered by a button, it would be a lot simpler.  In your example though, orderBy is auto-applied in the template

Comment: @Dan so I have to remove the orderBy applied in the template and create a function to handle the sorting in controller?

Comment: You don't have to, it's still doable, just easier to envision a solution with a button.  Will items be removable?

Comment: @Dan items are not removable, how do I make it doable?

Comment: I've left an answer to show one way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty basic directive that does the minimum you mentioned in comments.  It only orders the data once when it's first loaded, and isn't very reactive, but it lets you toggle and should be pretty easy to add watches, etc. for more features.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('ctrlMain', function($scope, filterFilter){
  $scope.reverse = false;  // <-- `reverse` boolean
  // Data
  $scope.results = [
    { name: "b" },
    { name: "g" },
    { name: "x" },
    { name: "a" },
    { name: "p" },
  ];
});
app.directive('orderer', function($filter) {
  return {
    scope: {
      data: '=orderer',
      reverse: '='
    },
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){
      scope.ordered = $filter('orderBy')(scope.data, 'name', scope.reverse);
      scope.formatted = [];
      
      scope.addRow = function(i, isAbove) {
        let index = i + !isAbove
        if (scope.reverse) {
          index = scope.ordered.length - index;
        }
        scope.ordered.splice(index, 0, { name: '*' });
      }
      scope.setFormatted = function(isReversed) {
       scope.formatted = scope.reverse ? scope.ordered.slice().reverse() : scope.ordered;
      };
      scope.$watch('reverse', function(n, o){
        scope.setFormatted();
      });
      scope.$watch('ordered', function(n, o){
        scope.setFormatted();
      }, true);
    },
    template: `
      <tr ng-repeat="item in formatted">
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="addRow($index, true)">O</button</td>
        <td><button ng-click="addRow($index, false)">U</button</td>
      </tr>
    `
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrlMain">
    <button ng-click="reverse = !reverse">toggle</button>
    <table>
      <tr><th>Header</th></tr>
      <tbody orderer="results" reverse="reverse"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```